# Zend Validator & Regex patterns

Tags: php, regex, validation, zend-framework

I am using Zend Frameworks Validation feature and am having trouble getting the Regex validator to work.

```
array(
    'name' => 'Regex',
    'options' => array(
        'pattern' => '[0-9a-zA-Z\s\'\.;\-]+',
            'messages' => array(
            \Zend\Validator\Regex::INVALID_CHARACTERS => "Invalid characters in address"
        )
    ),
)
```

I have various strings that need to accept letters, numbers, spaces and various characters, and I am using the code above for the various fields.

I've been reading [framework.zend.com](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.validate.set.html#zend.validate.set.regex) which doesn't give much detail.

My question is: Am I doing it correctly?
Is this how to use regex validator with Zend?
Any better examples of this floating around the web?

Thanks guys...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your pattern with:

```
'pattern' => '/[0-9a-zA-Z\s\'.;-]+/'
```

notices:

A regex pattern must be delimited. Here i have choosen `/` as delimiter, but you can use `#`, `~`, `@`, `|`, `` ` ``, ...

You don't have to escape special character as `.`, `$`, `|`, inside a character class. `;` is not a special character and doesn't need to be escaped inside or outside a character class.